# Formatting and lack of understanding

Tags: discussion

I was editing [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31353/in-order-to-solve-for-this-equation-for-heat-capacity-do-i-need-to-treat-it-as) the other day, and the user was working with both heat capacity ($C_p$) and temperature ($\mathrm{°C}$), but they had been using $C$ throughout the whole problem. Once I had gotten through editing the answer, they asked the question:

> In the first equation, what does $C$ designate?

What do you do in situations like these? I answered this question through editing it, but that isn't quite a formal answer.

Comment: I have rolled back your edits so that the question and its answer once again make sense.

Answer (score 5):

Even though editing questions to correct stuff like wrong units/representations is something we are encouraged to do, I believe you actually fell on a pitfall. The question is about the exact equations and units, so by changing them you ended up making the question a bit non-sense.

I think you shouldn't have edited it, at least not the bits involved in the actual question (anything related to $C$). Using Stack Overflow as an example, it is like editing someone's question to correct the code instead of only explaining what is wrong with it.

The question should probably be edited again to restore the problematic parts, because it doesn't make much sense to ask if $º\mathrm{C}$ is temperature or not.