# Should we not use MathJax in Tag Wiki excerpts?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

While going though the new tags, I spotted, that the [esters](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esters) was created, which eventually brought me back to the endeavour of tagging functional groups in general. ([Should we create tags for common functional groups?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2815/4945))

While I was editing a couple of questions, to include [nitro-compounds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nitro-compounds), I noticed that MathJax is not rendered in the pop-up. (I am very sorry for not adding hand drawn circles here.)

[image: screen shot edit tags]

On the Wiki page itself everything works as expected.

[image: screen shot tag wiki page]

**I would still think that it is a good thing to exclude MathJax from the Tag Wiki excerpts.**
What is your opinion?

Comment: If it is not supported in the pop-up, I think it is best to don't use it.

Comment: This ancient weird quasi-cool font we got here already suppresses numbers. It's ideal not to use MathJax, and even if we don't, we don't run into much trouble.

Comment: I'd say there's a bug here: I'm just not sure whether the bug is that MathJax doesn't work in the pop-ups, or that it *does* work for the excerpt on the tag wiki page. Either way, it should be consistent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree that it should be removed. I was the one who created the nitro-compounds tag and the wiki to go with it. I wasn't aware that MathJax didn't render in the excerpt popup but if I was then I wouldn't have used it. It doesn't seem essential to convey the meaning; it just makes it look a bit nicer.