# Shouldn’t every question be tagged with its division of chemistry?

Tags: discussion, tags

Walking through the questions something got me thinking. The tags [organic-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organic-chemistry), [inorganic-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inorganic-chemistry), [general-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-chemistry), [physical-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-chemistry), [analytical-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analytical-chemistry), [biochemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biochemistry), [quantum-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-chemistry),* [theoretical-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theoretical-chemistry)* and of course [lolic-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lolic-chemistry) seem to be the most general ones we have. Every question should more or less fit into *at least* one of these tags with possible subdivisions such as [medicinal-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicinal-chemistry) or [solid-state-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solid-state-chemistry).

Should we or should we not *require* every question to feature *at least* one of these major subdivisions and should we then not edit in the appropriate one to all remaining questions?

---

Sub-question assuming ‘yes’ on question 1: Is there a way to make this (or a similar) subset of tags a required set much like [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) etc. on meta?

---

*: I’m unsure which one of these has the larger scope; my guess is drifting towards [theoretical-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theoretical-chemistry) because I’m not sure if I would include [computational-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-chemistry) in [quantum-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-chemistry) but I’m going to leave that for the pros.

Comment: This is also what I think, how it should be.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87852/271002 (not conclusive)

Comment: +1  for "and of course lolic-chemistry".

Comment: Personally, I like the broad tags because it helps me know what questions to look at.  I can answer alot of questions in subtopics of inorganic chemistry and general chemistry but remember very little of organic, so it helps me find all the things I can look at answering.

Comment: @Mecury-197 that I believe is the only reason I'm not asking for tag burnination on meta.

Comment: Related to the footnote, there was once an effort: http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/391/4945

Comment: @Martin RE: the meta post, should we be burning those two manually in TRE?

Comment: I do not see a consensus there, so i'd opt for no. If you don't know what to do: http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/583/4945 There are about 100 q that need to be reviewed... and [tag:amines], [tag:esters], ...

Comment: @Jan What is 'lolic chemistry'?

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis An in-joke concerning the (then) tags of the [chat] room. It has since been removed. Read it as LOL-ic chemistry.

Comment: @Jan I get it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## A strong "no" to your second question. A less vigorous "no" to the former.

Here are my thoughts, a bit more classified than they usually tend to be:

#### No because the way other SEs deal with this:

Surprisingly unsurprisingly, broader tags exist in almost every SE. The chosen way of the Tag Lords™ is *broader tags shouldn't be applied to questions to which a more specific tag can be applied*. I prefer it this way also. I'll explain below.

#### Pro/Con comparison:

The benefits of having/requiring [organic-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organic-chemistry) where we have [alcohols](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alcohols) and we're talking about propanol is

- We'd exactly know how many organochem questions we have. $\color{red}{\mathcal{Yay}~for~\textbf{stats!}}$
- ?

The benefits of **not** having/requiring [organic-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organic-chemistry) where we have [alcohols](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alcohols) and we're talking about propanol is

- We have enough space for another useful tag.
- We're not introducing any redundant tags.
- We're avoiding a lot of confusion.
- We're avoiding a lot of [wasteful] work for retagging questions where the OP just added the tag *for the sake of avoiding the obligatory tag choice*.
- We're avoiding a lot of unnecessary arbitrary border drawing of "this should be a 'required tag' and this shouldn't".

Huh, this is obvious enough, no?

#### Meta experience:

A bit of meta experience tells me that first, to oblige anything outside the scope of the basic features of asking/answering/etc., you will need a *very*, very good reason.

Take as an example the downpour of stupid questions with a title like "HELP !!!. PROGRANNING QUESTION PROBLEMZ" on SO. It led to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/why-cant-we-use-the-word-problem-in-titles); and yet we subsequently see [The title word filter is one of the worst ideas ever implemented on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so). I still agree that the filter stops a lot of bad questions from being posted though.

Second, implementing and the results of implementing a feature are never as good as we depict them on paper to be. How many tags should be in the 'required' list? How do you get people and editors to comply with the recent decisions? How do you ensure you retagged everything? Or something more specific like "should we obligate [theoretical-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theoretical-chemistry) when a question can still be best tagged with [density-functional-theory](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/density-functional-theory)? etc etc. Basically, we're just producing work **that could be put to use in a better way, like [TRE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2940/the-great-retagging-event-episode-1-the-one-taggers?cb=1)**.

#### Meta tagging has a different system:

There are four tags in the 'required' list on meta, but do note that [discussion](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) is like an [other](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/other) tag: Any question that hasn't been sensibly and sufficiently tagged with [bug](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug), [feature-request](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [support](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) is tagged with [discussion](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion). Applying something alike to the main site just because we have a similar system here is insensible for obvious reasons.

Comment: (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻ That was just an example. But yeah, I wanted to make sure people say it's organic.

Comment: @Jan _some people_ includes IUPAC

Comment: This. This exactly is how it should be. Don't use five words when one will do. If [tag:density-functional-theory] is a subset of [tag:computational-chemistry], which is a subset of [tag:theoretical-chemistry], which is a subset of [tag:physical-chemistry], which is a subset of [tag:chemistry], which is a subset of [tag:science], which is a subset of [tag:you-get-the-idea] at what point do we stop requiring the parent tag?

Comment: @BenNorris Technically, this could (should?) mean we should ask for a tag *tree* rather than a tag *list* on meta … that would include the top groups with the sub-tag. But then again I fear that this is rather unique to chemistry, maybe biology and physics and maths but not many other Stack Exchanges …

Comment: @Jan I agree a tag tree would be much more useful. But no, a need for tag trees is sensed in pretty much *every* SE. i.e. the most popular tags on almost every SE are the broadest tags which have some subsets.

Comment: In that case I encourage you to take it to meta.SE, assuming it's not already there ;)

Comment: @Jan Considering the fact that it's not how the tags are currently supposed to be, I need a very good meta post and some well-thought reasoning to propose a change to the basis of the features here. And even then there are no guarantees that it will happen. Most important of all, ***I'm lazy***. So $\ldots$

Comment: Another pro for having the [tag:organic-chemistry]: Easier favorites for questions related to organic chemistry.

Comment: @Wytha not really, since people favorite for a variety of reasons. The "I love this question" reason usually isn't related to the tag. Unless yeah, a mod is favoriting questions with one specific tag to edit them.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M I meant favorite tags.

Comment: @Wytha then more specific tags are more favorable. I don't think ron, as an example of some organochem guy, would favorite that tag rather than, for instance, "reaction-mechanism".

Comment: I love how I keep *leaving out* tags such as organochem when I can use carbonyl-compounds etc. as a response to this meta question and then other people come to edit them (back) *in.*

Comment: Hmm, @Jan, I would decide it on a case by case basis. If a broader tag doesn't clutter up anything, it's but the least contribution to categorizing the question. Sure, if we have 4 suitable not-broad tags, then there shouldn't be any broad ones, ideally. But I would perhaps retag a question on TRE if it has a single not-broad tag.

Answer (score 1):

I just found an interesting statistic related to this question.

There are [14611 questions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22%22%20-%5Borganic-chemistry%5D%20-%5Binorganic-chemistry%5D%20-%5Bphysical-chemistry%5D%20-%5Banalytical-chemistry%5D%20%20-%5Btheoretical-chemistry%5D%20is%3Aquestion) **not** tagged with *any* of [organic-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organic-chemistry),
 [inorganic-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inorganic-chemistry), [physical-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-chemistry), [analytical-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analytical-chemistry), and  [theoretical-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theoretical-chemistry).

We also have [701 questions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-chemistry) on [quantum-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-chemistry), [625 questions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biochemistry) on [biochemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biochemistry), [1255 questions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/everyday-chemistry) on [everyday-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/everyday-chemistry), [129 questions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solid-state-chemistry+-physical-chemistry+-inorganic-chemistry+-experimental-chemistry) on [solid-state-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solid-state-chemistry), [667 questions](http://[experimental-chemistry]%20-[physical-chemistry]%20-[inorganic-chemistry]%20-[organic-chemistry]) on [experimental-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experimental-chemistry), and 0 questions on [general-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-chemistry) and [lolic-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lolic-chemistry).

Assuming nearly 1000 of these questions have been overcounted, we get a rough approximation of nearly **12000 questions *not* tagged with any field of chemistry.**  It is **$\approx47\%$** **of our total questions count!** (25389 questions currently) In all honestly, that's quite a *lot* of them. Much more than I expected.