# 'Structural-diagrams' tag disorder

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I seems to me that this tag is [seriously overused](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structural-diagrams).

Mistagging is one thing here, but shouldn't it be used only when [lewis-structure](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lewis-structure) doesn't apply?

EDIT: Yes, it's probably redundant, because after retagging there would be little to nothing left.

Answer (score 5):

Ahh, this I believe, is a similar case to [broad vs. subset](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/shouldn-t-every-question-be-tagged-with-its-division-of-chemistry?cb=1).

The lack of pointing to [lewis-structures](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lewis-structures) in its wiki could be a possible reason for some mistags. So I suggested an edit to the tag wiki. Is it a useful tag though? That could be another question.

Answer (score 4):

What the heck is a ‘structural diagram’ anyway? This sounds like some sort of weird graphic, i.e. diagrammatic representation of structures. But looking through the question what they *really* mean is a ‘structural formula’.

Most of these are probably either correctly tagged [lewis-structures](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lewis-structures) or maybe also [skeletal-formula](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skeletal-formula) (although the latter does not exist yet).

Can we nuke [structural-diagrams](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structural-diagrams), please?

Expanding this answer:

A Google search on *structural diagram* brought me [here](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Structural+Diagram) — an article from *the Great Soviet Encyclopedia* which apparantly used *structural diagram* as a synonym for *phase diagram.* And, of course, a nonzero set of Yahoo questions asking for structural formulae.

Also, the tag’s tag wiki describes a structural formula.

**Conclusion**

I still have no damn clue what a ‘structural diagram’ is — although someone hinted in the chat that a stereochemical projection could be meant. I question it though, until I am proven wrong. [skeletal-formula](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skeletal-formula) and/or [structural-formula](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structural-formula) should replace almost all occurrances of [structural-diagram](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structural-diagram) I can see so far.

Comment: +1! Also never heard about "structural diagrams" up until this day.

Comment: Hmm, I'm going to edit out the tag wiki. This TRE we'll be concentrating on retagging structural diagram questions.

Comment: Hmm, seems it indeed should be [structural formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_formula)

Comment: I would suggest retagging those questions with lewis-structure where possible and rename the rest to structural-formula (which can be done by a mod). I do not know how often it was used, but I have seen questions specifically about Fischer- or Newman-projection. (At least I believe I did.)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the previous answers and my comment earlier, I went ahead and renamed the tag to [structural-formula](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structural-formula).

[M.A.R. promised to propose a tag-wki.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24797781#24797781)

It seemed to be agreed, that this tag shall only be used, when not talking about [lewis-structure](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lewis-structure). Clean up is still necessary, but should have rather little impact.