# What are appropriate tag(s) for (organo)sulfur compounds?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Beginning in the middle of 2015 we successfully introduced [tags for common functional groups](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2815/should-we-create-tags-for-common-functional-groups). In this discussion it was noted that [thiols](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thiols) is rarely used and maybe not such a good tag therefore.<sup>[1]</sup> Lately [thioether](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thioether) was introduced and I thought that this will likely face the same problem. Since we graduated tags with single uses are not automatically culled (iirc), so that is no problem. However, I debate that the tag is actually useful.

Instead I am proposing the creation of a tag that has all kinds of sulfur or just [organosulfur compounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organosulfur_compounds) as a target.<sup>[2]</sup>
A very [quick search](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=thio*+is%3Aquestion) supports that there are enough uses of "thio" in questions to support such a tag.
I am, however, uncertain about the name and a scope. I was originally thinking of [thio-compounds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thio-compounds), but I could not find it in the [goldbook](http://goldbook.iupac.org/search.py?search_text=thio). I thought it would transport the meaning of a sulfur containing compound quite well.
I think that organosulfur is too specific as it would (kind of) exclude thiocyanate.
And just using [thio](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thio) seems to be just wrong, although the entry for the prefix [exists in the gooldbook](http://goldbook.iupac.org/T06347.html).

### Please go ahead, suggest names, propose scopes, discuss in general.

---

*Footnotes:*

1. I suggested then to include thiols in the alcohol tag. I'm not so sure this is a good idea any more.
2. We would still be keeping [thiols](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thiols) and [thioether](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thioether) as synonyms.

Comment: +1 for creating [tag:organosulfur-compounds] and having [tag:thiols] and [tag:thioether] as synonyms.

Comment: The [_Glossary of class names of organic compounds and reactivity intermediates based on structure (IUPAC Recommendations 1995)_](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/pac199567081307) mentions *thioethers* as the former name for *sulfides* $\ce{RSR}$.

Comment: +1 for organosulfur-compounds. I edited the thioether tag wiki  and mentioned sulfides.

Comment: @Geoff The link that Loong gave recommends the use of sulfides instead of thioethers, your edit suggests the opposite. However, if we introduce a new tag, and make the mentioned ones synonym of those, the tag-wiki will become an orphan and vanish. Since it seems to be on the way to consensus, that such a tag will be created any changes to any of the wiki will be lost eventually. (The last part is not 100% true, it just needs mod privileges to find the orphans.)

Comment: @Martin-マーチン - I think the tag wiki edit was about 5 minutes of work. I certainly don't care if it vanishes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Editorial Note:*
>   The tag [organosulfur-compounds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organosulfur-compounds) has been created with mappings to [thiols](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thiols) and [thioether](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thioether).
>
> Original post follows.

[organosulfur](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organosulfur) or [organosulfur-compounds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organosulfur-compounds)

While thiols and thoethers already exist, this tag can cover a wide range of other compounds, including:

- Thioesters
- Thioureas
- Xanthates
- Thioacetals
- Sulfoxides
- Sulfones
- Sulfolanes
- Sulfonic acids
- Sulfinic acids
- Disulfides
- [You get the idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organosulfur_compounds)

Most of these functional groups are not as common as their analogs, so having individual tags for each is counterproductive.

Comment: What about thiocyanates or thiosulfates, they would not be covered. Do you think they should not be covered in this tag?

Comment: @Martin-マーチン - Can you find a thiosulfate question that really cries out for such a tag?

Comment: @Geoff I don't know. I'm not sure. I also have not properly checked. We included inorganic esters in [tag:esters], so I just wanted to clarify that point before we go ahead and introduce the tag.