# Will this question be well received here?

Tags: support, allowed-questions, specific-question

Preference to longest carbon chain or double bond?

[image]

Above structure and its nomenclature is given in my book. However, I suspect it is wrong because the Carbon chain of 8 instead of 7 is available. So my question is do we give preference to double bond over the number of carbon in a chain during nomenclature?

I found [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/74284/longest-chain-iupac-rule?noredirect=1&lq=1) question here but it only makes me more confuse as its answer states that we give preference to the carbon chain. So is my book outdated(which is possible) or is there any other rule which I am unaware of?

Will this question be well received here? I am a bit hesitant to ask this question.

Comment: Related: [Asking nomenclature questions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3120/7951)

Comment: I think in principle the question itself is almost fine. If you take an example from a book, you must include a proper citation, so that it can be referred to as erratum, or the error does not appear without context. You do kind of answer your question already. The question you link to cites the rule you need, it is very likely that your book is outdated.

Comment: @Martin  it is not really a book but notes given by my teacher. I already asked the [question]( https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/117010/priority-to-longest-carbon-chain-or-double-bond).

Comment: @user541396 You write 'my book' twice, please be precise about your source.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I will correct it. Sorry.