# Suggestions for the new ask page

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

The [Ask page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) has been changed; see also [The new ask page is now live on the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513).
I am writing this meta question as [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) so that we can collect ideas about how we can make the best use of the new features on Chemistry. If we reach consensus on a proposal, we could write the corresponding [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) later.

For example, the contents of the "Draft your question" sidebar on Chemistry are still limited to a short standard text:

[image]

On Physics, however, the sidebar has a longer custom text:

[image]

I guess a useful sidebar on Chemistry could look quite similar. In particular, it could include a link to our [homework guidance](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/142/7951). By the way, our homework guidance already has a (unfortunately well-hidden) similar attempt to guide new users through the (old) ask page:

[image]

We could also think about tag-related error warnings like this one:

[image]

For example, we could link the [nomenclature](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature) tag to a short version of our guidelines on [how to ask nomenclature questions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3120/7951).

Comment: In the body instead of generic inputs as to how to write a question I firmly advocate telling users what not to do. Direct concise hw policy

Comment: I don't think this needs to be all that complicated. Just put whatever you see yourself putting in the comments to new users; and [canned comments](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3205/7448) are a good start. (Absolutely shameless plug) It probably has to be written in an answer below, and put to a vote, but that would require too much stamina and I'm lazy.

Comment: "Typeset chemical formulas in the body (e.g. \$\ce{HCO3-(aq)}\$, which will appear as $\ce{HCO3-(aq)}$) but not in the title (e.g. HCO3(-) (aq))"