# What is wrong about my answer?

Tags: support, answers

I have a question about my Chemistry Stack Exchange post: [When we name an organic compound ,if there is double bond and a functional group which is now a substituent who has priority?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/134568/when-we-name-an-organic-compound-if-there-is-double-bond-and-a-functional-group/134569#134569)

I do not understand, why my answer has been downvoted and afterwards deleted. Is there any mistake in the answer?

Edit: The same goes about my only question: [What are inorganic nomenclature principles used in different languages?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/134566/what-are-inorganic-nomenclature-principles-used-in-different-languages) I really do not know what I did so much wrong, that I got 3 downvotes. I know how this site works, as I am more active at Stack Overflow, but I never met such treatment any time at this site. If one downvoted, one usually wrote the reason, what is wrong with the question. However, from this site, I have just the feeling of not being welcomed by anyone, which is quite sad.

Comment: I downvoted your answer because it was clearly wrong. However, I didn't flag your answer since it was clearly an attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was the one who deleted it, and I already replied to your flag asking the same thing.
Your answer was scoring −2 at the moment of deletion, and was to be read as follows:

> According to the IUPAC's Blue Book published in 2013, alcohols are preferred to be included before double bonds.

First, a one-liner consisting of one sentence can *very rarely* be considered an answer at all, and is usually much better suited as a comment.

Second, I suggest giving [How to ask and answer nomenclature questions?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3066/how-to-ask-and-answer-nomenclature-questions) a good read. Your answer was lacking a complete reference and no  nomenclature rules were quoted, hence rendering the "answer" as non-trustworthy.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. Of course, I would post a comment, however, I do not have enough reputation at this time to do so. Then I just wanted help to the person asking the question.

Comment: @AdamKnirsch I see how Chemistry.SE could be a harsh place for the beginners. It might be a bumpy ride at first, but keep in mind that all the downvotes are only ranking the *post's content* , not you as a person or your abilities. Observe, do simple editing, maybe participate in [chats](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=chemistry.stackexchange.com) sometimes, and you are going to be fine.

Comment: @andselisk Thank you for kind words. It can be very demotivating seeing all the downvotes without any explanation. But I will try my best to fit in there as chemistry will be my subject at university for at least the next 5 years.

Answer (score 4):

<s>There's *technically* not much wrong with your answer; **P-14.4** of the 2013 Blue Book backs up your statement (of course, the situation can get more confusing with more complicated molecules, but that's not the point).</s> I misread the question; it has nothing to do with **P-14.4** at all. The correct answer is complicated by the fact that there is a carboxylic acid. In this case, the rules say that the longer chain must be chosen (**P-44.3.2**), and it doesn't actually matter which chain has the alcohol or the alkene, you have to choose the longer one.

Anyway, the main problem with your answer is that it's just too short, and the claim isn't backed up by quotation from the Blue Book or some other source.

As for your question, I cannot claim that I know why people downvoted, but my take on it is that it's not the most suitable question for SE, in that you're asking for an enumeration (or list) of possible answers. This is generally frowned upon across the entire SE network. Karsten's comment on your question:

> You might want to make your question a bit more specific, or do some research first and then ask about a smaller set of languages.

is a good suggestion. I don't, however, agree with the suggestion of "in your native language, ..." You are right that this will almost certainly attract closure. Questions shouldn't have an answer that depends on the identity of the answerer.