# Would this improve my Chemistry question re deducing the IUPAC name of LSD, or, if that is no longer an option, be a good question in its own right?

Tags: discussion, chemical-formulas

People have said in the comments of my question [IUPAC naming of lysergic acid diethylamide (LSD) heterocyclic core and its locants](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/169432/how-might-a-chemist-deduce-the-iupac-name-of-lysergic-acid-diethylamide-lsd-fr) that the question would take many pages to answer, and/or that I wouldn't understand the answers due to my not knowing enough about chemistry.

Trying to do some research for the question with Google I found that someone had asked almost the exact same question in 2018 and never got an answer: https://www.chemicalforums.com/index.php?topic=95212.0

At one point he said, "Currently, I have only found 2 IUPAC names for LSD: 9,10-didehydro-N,N-diethyl-6-methylergoline-8β-carboxamide, which is easy to follow but doesn't offer much (sic) with the naming of complex polycyclic/aromatic compounds because the cores (sic)  structure is simplified to -ergoline; and (6aR,9R)-N,N-diethyl-7-methyl-4,6,6a,7,8,9-hexahydroindolo[4,3-fg]quinoline-9-carboxamide from the Wikipedia page which (sic) is very confusing and could use come (sic) clarification."

Would you agree with him that the shorter IUPAC name is "easy to follow"? It's not easy for me, and it therefore occurred to me that if I asked about this supposedly easier IUPAC name instead, then my question would be improved.

What do you think?

Edit: Since Mithoron, with my consent, has taken the question in a somewhat new direction, with several upvotes as result, I don't think I'd like to rewrite it. So I wonder whether a question about deducing or explaining why or how the (much easier, although still very hard for a beginner like me) IUPAC name  9,10-didehydro-N,N-diethyl-6-methylergoline-8β-carboxamide can be deduced from the skeletal formula for LSD would be well-received on Chemistry? What do you think?

Comment: Well, when I asked you to tell what you knew, this was on the oft chance you knew more than finding longest chain, which isn't applicable in this example :( You can't just make a diary of a question. I could rewrite it to be useful, but it would be probably  unrecognisable after that, and you still wouldn't be able to decode the name.

Comment: This analysis you link looks OK, if you could catch up to the point that poster was in, that perhaps could give you chance to get it all.

Comment: You made a pretty impressive effort, though. If more beginners did half as much, it would be a better site.

Comment: Well, I rewrote it, what do you think.

Comment: Possibly useful: https://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/93/r93_35.htm

Comment: @BuckThorn these are still the old recommendations from 1993, but you can find the whole blue book here: https://iupac.qmul.ac.uk/BlueBook/

Comment: Well, the post suggested you're beginner as far as organic nomenclature is concerned. Now you're a bit more advanced, I guess ;)

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I posted that link not as a resource for learning specifics of nomenclature rules (which are rapidly evolving?) but rather as a helpful introduction to the purpose of the subject.

Comment: @BuckThorn As an introduction, you might want to link to the [Brief guide to the nomenclature of organic chemistry (IUPAC Technical Report 2020)](https://doi.org/10.1515/pac-2019-0104). It can also be found (well hidden) in the tag info of the nomenclature tag.

Comment: You also might want to consider [Asking nomenclature questions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3120/103369) and [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Mithoron If you think you would "accept" an answer to the LSD question if it were your actual official question of your own and you were therefore able to do so, please let me know and I will click on the green check mark of that question.

Comment: Well, I doubt you could get a better answer for that. Loong even went a bit beyond what I tried to limit it to.